# How do I change the column names of a table in Apache Superset?

Tags: apache-superset

I would like the names of the columns in the table below to be different from the names of the columns in the database.
For example by changing "COD_STAT" to "Station ID".

[image: change_table_column_names]

How can this be done?

Answer (score 7):

You need to add **VERBOSE NAME** to your columns. You can perform it by following next steps:

1. Explore your chart and choose tab **EDIT DATASOURCE** by clicking on your **DATASOURCE** button.
2. In the lower left corner of opened window you can find button **USE LEGACY DATASOURCE EDITOR**. Click on it.
3. In the **EDIT TABLE** window pick the tab **COLUMNS**. Now you can edit required columns and add **VERBOSE NAME** which will replace your db names after saving.

[image]

Comment: Would be nice to have this option on viz level so that the data source stays untouched

Answer (score 7):

Open your chart, then click the dots next to your datasource and pick "edit dataset"

[image]

Then click "Columns" and change the "Label" attribute:

[image]

Comment: If you need to do this for aggregates in metrics, click the arrow next to your field (in metrics) then click the pencil next to the field name and edit it. This is sometimes buggy and won't save or there is a lag on save occasionally.

Answer (score 4):

Here are the steps:

1. Click to Charts.
   [image]
2. Goto Datasource dropdown and click on edit data source:
   [image]
3. Select the dimension you want to modify by clicking the drop down:
   [image]
4. You will find Label option and here you can enter your own title (For you, it's station ID).
   [image]

Comment: hello, I am changing column type there but in sql editor still same type comes

Comment: maybe try using CAST(<COLUMN> as string)